# XMPP: Why do we send multiple requests to open a stream for one connection?

Tags: xmpp

I've been following a number of tutorials, the best being [Yandex's](http://api.yandex.com/disk/doc/dg/concepts/xmpp_xmpp-connection.xml).

In step 6, it says I need to open the stream again after authorization? Is there any reason why?

Did the stream close automatically? If I just authenticated the stream, why does it need to close and be reopened? Do I need to recursively start from step 1 again or how often do I need to request it to be reopened? Do I need to authenticate this new stream.

As a XMPP beginner, why's the point of: New Stream -> Authorize it -> New Stream -> Not sure now what, maybe authorize again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream features change after authorization. Just as they change after the TLS handshake is performed. A change of stream features always means that there is a "new" stream going on. That's why the stream is "reopened".

If you look at [RFC 6120 § 9.1](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#examples-c2s), you see that a server (could) first announce (only) `starttls` as stream feature (9.1.1 Step 3):

```
S: <stream:features>
     <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'>
       <required/>
     </starttls>
   </stream:features>
```

then after the server and client performed TLS negotiation and the established TLS a **new stream** is initiated by the client.

Now the server sends different stream features (9.1.2. Step 8):

```
S: <stream:features>
     <mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
       <mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1-PLUS</mechanism>
       <mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism>
       <mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
     </mechanisms>
   </stream:features>
```

Notice how the `starttls` stream feature disappeared and now only the SASL mechanisms are reported as stream feature.

After the client is authenticated another **new stream** is created and again new stream features are send (9.1.3 step 14):

```
<stream:features>
    <bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'/>
</stream:features>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an XMPP beginner, you may just get an [XMPP library](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) which done things right :)

When you ready to go deeper, you must read official XMPP specifications: [Core](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120), [Instant Messaging and Presence](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121) and [Address Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6122)

Initial stream "negotiation" described here - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-4.3
In a short - no, you need authenticate only when your party "advertise" `<auth ... />` element in the beginning of new stream (`<stream:features>`), most of time it is done once.